# instruction set emulator guide

Tags: emulation, instructions, microprocessors, instruction-set

I am interested in writing emulators like for gameboy and other handheld consoles, but I read the first step is to emulate the instruction set. I found a link here that said for beginners to emulate the Commodore 64 8-bit microprocessor, the thing is I don't know a thing about emulating instruction sets. I know mips instruction set, so I think I can manage understanding other instruction sets, but the problem is what is it meant by emulating them?

NOTE: If someone can provide me with a step-by-step guide to instruction set emulation for beginners, I would really appreciate it.

NOTE #2: I am planning to write in C.

NOTE #3: This is my first attempt at learning the whole emulation thing.

Thanks

EDIT: I found this site that is a detailed step-by-step guide to writing an emulator which seems promising. I'll start reading it, and hope it helps other people who are looking into writing emulators too.

[Emulator 101](http://www.emulator101.com/)

Comment: If you want to get started with emulation, I recommend you do something simpler like Chip-8.

Comment: I think this would be a good idea, because the 6502 has many instructions to do.

Comment: Yeah, and the Chip-8 only has one addressing mode too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An instruction set emulator is a software program that reads binary data from a software device and carries out the instructions that data contains as if it were a physical microprocessor accessing physical data.

The Commodore 64 used a 6502 Microprocessor. I wrote an emulator for this processor once. The first thing you need to do is read the datasheets on the processor and learn about its behavior. What sort of opcodes does it have, what about memory addressing, method of IO. What are its registers? How does it start executing? These are all questions you need to be able to answer before you can write an emulator.

Here is a general overview of how it would look like in C (Not 100% accurate):

```
uint8_t RAM[65536]; //Declare a memory buffer for emulated RAM (64k)
uint16_t A; //Declare Accumulator
uint16_t X; //Declare X register
uint16_t Y; //Declare Y register
uint16_t PC = 0; //Declare Program counter, start executing at address 0
uint16_t FLAGS = 0 //Start with all flags cleared;

//Return 1 if the carry flag is set 0 otherwise, in this example, the 3rd bit is
//the carry flag (not true for actual 6502)
#define CARRY_FLAG(flags)  ((0x4 & flags) >> 2)

#define ADC 0x69
#define LDA 0xA9

while (executing) {
    switch(RAM[PC]) {  //Grab the opcode at the program counter
        case ADC: //Add with carry
            A = X + RAM[PC+1] + CARRY_FLAG(FLAGS);
            UpdateFlags(A);
            PC += ADC_SIZE;
            break;
        case LDA: //Load accumulator
            A = RAM[PC+1]; 
            UpdateFlags(X);
            PC += MOV_SIZE;
            break;
        default:
            //Invalid opcode!

    }
}
```

According to [this reference](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/6502opcodes.html) ADC actually has 8 opcodes in the 6502 processor, which means you will have 8 different ADC in your switch statement, each one for different opcodes and memory addressing schemes. You will have to deal with endianess and byte order, and of course pointers. I would get a solid understanding of pointer and type casting in C if you dont already have one. To manipulate the flags register you have to have a solid understanding of bitwise operations in C. If you are clever you can make use of C macros and even function pointers to save yourself some work, as the CARRY_FLAG example above.

Every time you execute an instruction, you must advance the program counter by the size of that instruction, which is different for each opcode. Some opcodes dont take any arguments and so their size is just 1 byte, while others take 16-bit integers as in my MOV example above. All this should be pretty well documented.

Branch instructions (JMP, JE, JNE etc) are simple: If some flag is set in the flags register then load the PC to the address specified. This is how "decisions" are made in a microprocessor and emulating them is simply a matter of changing the PC, just as the real microprocessor would do.

The hardest part about writing an instruction set emulator is debugging. How do you know if everything is working like it should? There are plenty of resources for helping you. People have written test codes that will help you debug every instruction. You can execute them one instruction at a time and compare the reference output. If something is different, you know you have a bug somewhere and can fix it.

This should be enough to get you started. The important thing is that you have A) A good solid understanding of the instruction set you want to emulate and B) a solid understanding of low level data manipulation in C, including type casting, pointers, bitwise operations, byte order, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.
I'll start reading the datasheets